# Format object in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My application is in react and redux technology.

I created a helper that formats my account bill and money, like this:

```
export const formatBill = (bill) => ({
  ...bill,
  amountMoney: bill.amountMoney?.toLocaleString(undefined, {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  }),
  accountBillNumber: bill.accountBillNumber
    .replace(/(^\d{2}|\d{4})+?/g, '$1 ')
    .trim(),
});
```

Thanks to this, I can do something in the redux reducer and it works great:

```
...
case GET_BILLS_SUCCESS:
  draft.bills = action.bills.map(formatBill);
  break;
...
```

Now I have a problem because I would like to use this function for the transfer history. The problem is that my payload doesn't look so friendly. It's similar to this:

```
transactions: {
      data: [
        {
          amountMoney: '10.00',
          recipientBill: {
            uuid: '8b9cef86-3987-4a71-badc-996caca8d8e0',
            accountBillNumber: '19282292972339385206612752',
            currency: {
              name: 'PLN',
            },
            user: {
              uuid: 'c58a9b81-2d16-4b07-804d-0b1fc34381ed',
            }
          },
          senderBill: {
            uuid: '6308be25-5bde-4f63-83d1-7bd47a829e61',
            accountBillNumber: '76282292974456140174811708',
            currency: {
              name: 'USD',
            },
            user: {
              uuid: 'af031321-f64b-4e91-948b-0c8c8ac4804c',
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      meta: {
        page: 1,
        take: 10,
        itemCount: 1,
        pageCount: 1
      }
    };
```

so now I would like to `formatBill()` the bill in `recipientBill.accountBillNumber` and `senderBill.accountBillNumber` How can I save this nicely in the redux reducer? I tried to solve this problem similar to this, but this is not the right solution:

```
case GET_TRANSACTION_HISTORY_SUCCESS:
  draft.transactions.data = [
    action.transactions.data.map((transaction) =>
      formatBill(transaction.recipientBill),
    ),
    action.transactions.meta,
  ];

  break;
```